Partial derivatives of Christoffel symbols to Covariant derivatives
I wanted to express this thing: $g^{ab}\partial_c\Gamma^c_{ab} - g^{ab}\partial_a\Gamma^c_{cb}$, in terms of a covariant derivative. I figured out that if you swap $a$ and $c$ in the $\partial \Gamma$ terms you get the same quantity so I thought I could anti-simetrize the expression but I couldn´t get something useful. Any ideas?

You can't formally take the covariant derivative of non-tensorial objects, so it won't be applicable to the connection terms.
